# Unmask environment variables in Circle CI logs

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, circleci

It seems like Circle CI masks all environment variables in its log by replacing them with asterisks (`*`).

The result would be comical if it wasn't so irritating. Harmless values like `prod` or `dev` get masked which totally mangles normal, non-sensitive information. The name of our org gets mangled in URLs so they become broken links. Sometimes it takes a very long time to figure out what the unmasked value would have been, and yet it is necessary to know it to debug an issue.

Is there a way to disable this masking somehow, or get around this issue in any way? We do have some sensitive environment variables in Circle contexts, but the majority are not sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The [secrets masking feature](https://circleci.com/docs/env-vars/#secrets-masking) is enabled by default. You need to contact CircleCI Support so they disable it for the related project.